# Using OpenCV image for Azure recognition service

Tags: python-3.x, azure, opencv

I have an already opened OpenCV image in Python 3 that I would like to send to Azure recognition service.

I know that I can read my image in binary mode by `open` and send it to Azure service by using following [code](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/educator-developer-blog/digitize-your-notes-with-azure-computer-vision-and-python/ba-p/3259276):

```
from azure.cognitiveservices.vision.computervision import ComputerVisionClient
from msrest.authentication import CognitiveServicesCredentials

image_file="........"
subscription_key = "........"
endpoint = "......"

computervision_client = ComputerVisionClient(endpoint,CognitiveServicesCredentials(subscription_key))

with open(image_file, "rb") as image:
    read_response = computervision_client.read_in_stream(image, raw=True)
```

In OpenCV I would read my image by

```
import cv2
image_file=cv2.imread(image_file)
```

How to convert the already read in OpenCV image so that it can be sent to the client? I do not want to read again my picture by `open`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to convert the already read in OpenCV image so that it can be sent
> to the client? I do not want to read again my picture by  `open`.

You can make use of **imencode** method of OpenCV to stream the image as a byte in the memory, Refer the code below:-

```py
import  cv2

from  azure.cognitiveservices.vision.computervision  import  ComputerVisionClient

from  msrest.authentication  import  CognitiveServicesCredentials

import  io

import  time

from  azure.core.exceptions  import  HttpResponseError

from  azure.cognitiveservices.vision.computervision.models  import  OperationStatusCodes

#from azure.core.serialization import De

  

# replace with your own Azure subscription key and endpoint

subscription_key = "<subscription-key"

endpoint = "<end-point>"

  

# create a ComputerVisionClient object with Azure authentication

computervision_client = ComputerVisionClient(endpoint, CognitiveServicesCredentials(subscription_key))

  

# read the image with OpenCV

image = cv2.imread("letter-to-santa-claus.png")

  

# encode the image as a jpeg in memory

retval, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', image)

jpeg_bytes = buffer.tobytes()

  

# create an IO stream to wrap the bytes data

image_stream = io.BytesIO(jpeg_bytes)

  
  

response = computervision_client.read_in_stream(image_stream, raw=True)

read_operation_location = response.headers["Operation-Location"]

# Grab the ID from the URL

operation_id = read_operation_location.split("/")[-1]

# Retrieve the results

while  True:

read_result = computervision_client.get_read_result(operation_id)

if  read_result.status.lower() not  in ['notstarted', 'running']:

break

time.sleep(1)

# Get the detected text

if  read_result.status == OperationStatusCodes.succeeded:

for  page  in  read_result.analyze_result.read_results:

for  line  in  page.lines:

# Print line

print(line.text)
```

Output:-

[image]

Comment: You can use retval, buffer = cv2.imencode('.png', image) to avoid image manipulation